# Display a table of strings and their variations per row (R)

Tags: r, frequency

For a large database, I would like to find a solution where I could predefine the strings to be searched and then get a table that would contain the frequency of these strings and their possible variations per row.

```
strings <- c("dog", "cat", "mouse")

var1 <- c("black dog", "white dog", "angry dog", "dogs and cats are nice", "dog")
var2 <- c("white cat", "black cat", "tiny cat", NA, "cow")
var3 <- c("little mouse", "big mouse", NA, NA, "mouse")
data <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
```

The result should look like this while I am looking for *dog*, *cat* and *mouse*:

```
dog&cat 4
mouse 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may try

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, data)
stack(setNames(lapply(c( "\\bdog.*\\bcat|\\bcat.*\\bdog", "mouse"), 
    \(pat) sum(grepl(pat, v1))), c("dog&cat", "mouse")))[2:1]
      ind values
1 dog&cat      4
2   mouse      3
```

---

Or if we need all the combinations

```
lst1 <- lapply(c(strings, combn(strings, 2, FUN = \(x) 
   sprintf("\\b%1$s.*\\b%2$s|\\b%2$s.*\\b%1$s", x[1], x[2]))), 
    \(pat) sum(grepl(pat, v1)))
names(lst1) <- c(strings, combn(strings, 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "&"))
stack(lst1)[2:1]
        ind values
1       dog      5
2       cat      4
3     mouse      3
4   dog&cat      4
5 dog&mouse      3
6 cat&mouse      2
```

---

For more combinations, it may be better to use `Reduce` with individually applying `grepl`

```
lst1 <- lapply(1:3, \(n) {
   vals <- colSums(combn(strings, n, 
  FUN = \(pats) Reduce(`&`, lapply(pats, \(pat) grepl(pat, v1)))))
   nms <- combn(strings, n, FUN = paste, collapse = "&")
   setNames(vals, nms)
   })
stack(unlist(lst1))[2:1]
            ind values
1           dog      5
2           cat      4
3         mouse      3
4       dog&cat      4
5     dog&mouse      3
6     cat&mouse      2
7 dog&cat&mouse      2
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  unite(var, everything(), na.rm = TRUE, sep = " ") %>% 
  summarise(`dog&cat` = sum(str_detect(var,
   "\\bdog.*\\bcat|\\bcat.*\\bdog")),
     mouse = sum(str_detect(var, 'mouse'))) %>%   
  pivot_longer(everything())
```

-output

```
 # A tibble: 2 × 2
  name    value
  <chr>   <int>
1 dog&cat     4
2 mouse       3
```

Comment: I really like these soulutions, thank you very much. The problem is that I only want to predefine the strings but not the potential variations.

Comment: @onlyjust17 The 'strings' object doesn't mention about the dog &cat.  Is it by choice? or are you also looking into cat&mouse, dog&mouse etc?

Comment: Yes, I just want to specify the strings, that's why I didn't put dog&cat. I want the command to detect by itself if there is any variation (cat&mouse, dog&mouse, etc.) at all. It should list all variations.

Comment: @onlyjust17 okay, got, it.  So you want all possible pairwise combinations as well as single ones?  I find only 'mouse' and not dog or cat alone in your expected

Comment: Indeed, although I would like to see up to 15 strings in practice.

Comment: @onlyjust17 try the update

Comment: Works well with this data frame, thank you very much! Is this command able to display combinations with more strings such as dog&cat&cow? If not, where should I edit it?

Comment: @onlyjust17 Here, I used only for 1, and 2 combinations.  if you want more concatenate to `combn` with 3 i.e. `combn(strings, 3,..` and make the changes in the pattern

Comment: @onlyjust17 please note that the `grepl` with combinations greater than 2 would be better if you perform those individually and then `Reduce` with `&`

Comment: @onlyjust17 updated the solution to take care of that

Comment: I want to select columns from an xls file as a data source. I can't figure out where to define this in your code.

Comment: @onlyjust17  In the `base R`, version, we use the whole data i.e. `v1 <- do.call(paste, data)`  If you need to select columns, subset with `v1 <- do.call(paste, data[yourcolumnsofinterest])`

Comment: Strangely, I've never used a base R before. Good to know, thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error message: `Error in combn(strings, n, FUN = function(pats) Reduce(`&`, lapply(pats, : n < m.` I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: @onlyjust17 if your vector elements length are less than the combinations, you get that error.  Otherwise, it works.  Here, you have length of 3, thus it works from 1 to 3

Comment: I understand everything now! Thank you.